# Read CSV file with embedded double quotes and commas

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I am trying to read a dirty CSV file using the fread() function from the data.table package but have a problem with embedded double quotes and commas in the string values, that is, unescaped double quotes present in a quoted field. The following example data illustrates my problem. It consists of 3 lines/rows and 6 columns, with the first line containing the column names:

```
"SA","SU","CC","CN","POC","PAC"
"NE","R","000","H "B", O","1","8"
"A","A","000","P","E,5","8"
```

The first problem is in line 2 which has an embedded pair of double quotes and a comma: `"H "B", O"`. The second problem is in line 3 which has a comma within the double quotes: `"E,5"`. I have tried the following:

**Attempt 1**

```
library(data.table)
x1 <- fread(file = "example.csv", quote = "\"")
```

Output:

```
> x1
     V1 "SA" "SU"   "CC" "CN" "POC" "PAC"
1: "NE"  "R"    0 "H "B"   O"   "1"     8
2:  "A"  "A"    0    "P"   "E    5"     8
```

Message:

> Found and resolved improper quoting in first 100 rows. If the fields
>   are not quoted (e.g. field separator does not appear within any
>   field), try quote="" to avoid this warning.Detected 6 column names but
>   the data has 7 columns (i.e. invalid file). Added 1 extra default
>   column name for the first column which is guessed to be row names or
>   an index. Use setnames() afterwards if this guess is not correct, or
>   fix the file write command that created the file to create a valid
>   file.

Conclusion: the result is incorrect because it adds a new column `V1`.

**Attempt 2**

```
x2 <- fread(file = "example.csv", quote = "")
```

Output:

```
> x2
     V1 "SA"  "SU"   "CC" "CN" "POC" "PAC"
1: "NE"  "R" "000" "H "B"   O"   "1"   "8"
2:  "A"  "A" "000"    "P"   "E    5"   "8"
```

Message:

> Detected 6 column names but the data has 7 columns (i.e. invalid
>   file). Added 1 extra default column name for the first column which is
>   guessed to be row names or an index. Use setnames() afterwards if this
>   guess is not correct, or fix the file write command that created the
>   file to create a valid file.

Conclusion: the result is incorrect because it adds a new column `V1`..

**Solution?**

What I am looking for is a way to get an output similar to

```
> x3
   SA SU CC       CN POC PAC
1: NE  R  0 H 'B', O   1   8
2:  A  A  0        P E,5   8
```

preferably using fread(), but other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try cleaning your data beforehand and replace the double quotes with single quotes.

```
x = readLines('my_file.csv')
y = gsub('","', "','", x) # replace double quotes for each field
y = gsub('^"|"$', "'", y) # replace trailing and leading double quotes
z = paste(y, collapse='\n') # turn it back into a table for fread to read
df = fread(z, quote="'")
df

   SA SU CC       CN POC PAC
1: NE  R  0 H "B", O   1   8
2:  A  A  0        P E,5   8
```

I can't confirm that this is efficient since I don't know how big your file is, but it might be a worthwhile approach.

Comment: I have considered this, but wonder if it is possible to do using fread() or some other read function e.g. readr::read_delim() via parameters. Reading the documentation for fread() it hints that it can handle these issues automatically, but I cannot find out how.

Comment: Are you on Linux? `fread` has the `cmd` parameter that allows code execution to be performed on the file prior to reading it in, so you might be able to use `awk` or `sed` to preprocess, which would prevent having to load it into memory before processing. Not sure of the advantages there though.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. Do you mean a shell command via the `input` parameter in fread()?

Comment: I can't test this right now since I'm on win10 with no access to *nix, but I think it would be something like `fread('my_file.csv', cmd="sed s/","/','/g;s/^"|"$/'/g my_file.csv")`. **I'd highly recommend creating a backup of your file before trying this!**